# IPython's Qt event-loop integration doesn't consistently launch a QApplication

Tags: python, qt, ipython

I'm developing a Qt application with a non-blocking IPython console through which the user can bypass the GUI if needed. I've prepared a simple example called qt_app.py which checks for an already-existing QApplication:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication.instance()
print(app)
```

Let's try running the following:

```
ipython --gui qt5
%run qt_app.py
```

The output displays a handle to a QApplication:

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication object at 0x000001323D112678>
```

However, if I try to launch IPython and run the script in one line,

```
ipython --gui qt5 qt_app.py
```

QApplication.instance() returns None.

As a second example, consider the script qt_app2.py:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.magic('gui qt5')
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication.instance()
print(app)
```

If I open an IPython console and run this once, no QApplication is created, but it appears if I run it again:

```
In [1]: %run qt_app2.py
None

In [2]: %run qt_app2.py
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication object at 0x0000020008606C18>
```

It seems that IPython is creating the QApplication *after* executing the rest of the code - maybe in the next step of its internal event loop? My application is run from a separate launcher script which uses a call to os.system to run the application in an IPython console, and this inconsistency breaks this functionality. Is there a way to resolve this?

I'm using IPython 7.3.0 and PyQt5 5.11.3.

Comment: use `app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()` `if app is None:` `app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])`

Comment: This leads to blocking behavior (i.e. no IPython console input is possible while the QApplication is running). As I understand it, if app is None after the first line, it's because Qt hasn't detected an already existing QApplication created by IPython, so the event loop integration doesn't work.